# nginx map directive not working with subnet masks

Tags: nginx, web-server

Is there something special needed to match subnets in nginx when using `map`? I have the below configuration in the `http {}` block. The client IP is 10.0.3.1. If i remove the `10.0.3.1` entry it always returns deny instead of matching the 10.0.3.0/24 subnet. Is there a nginx module required that i'm missing or something ?

I'm basing this config on some blog articles but can't find any official documentation to say this notation is supported.

```
map $remote_addr $allowed {
     10.0.3.1 allow;
     10.0.2.0/24 allow;
     10.0.3.0/24 allow;
     default deny;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `map` directive maps strings, so it is possible to represent `10.0.3.0/24` as a regular expression and continue to use the `map` directive. But have you considered the `geo` directive that does support IP address syntax?

```
geo $allowed {
 10.0.3.1 allow;
 10.0.2.0/24 allow;
 10.0.3.0/24 allow;
 default deny;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html#geo) for details.